# Html rendering does not follow critical rendering path

Tags: javascript, html, rendering

I am writing an example about how the critical rendering path works. Below is index.html my sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>1</div>
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: green !important;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="./test.js"></script>
    <div>2</div>
    <script src="./test2.js"></script>
    <div>3</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

the test.js and the same as test2.js will alert a message like this:

```
alert('test')
```

```
`alert('test 2')`
```

Please aware that the these script will execute when it finish download immediately without waiting for onload event.

I thought the result when browser load the html is 2 of alert pop out when UI render NOTHING.
But i'm wrong. They render something on UI already (the background color and the number).

1st alert:

[image]

2nd alert:

[image]

My questions is:
why browser can renders anything on UI before all the script code finish executed?
does html parser work line by line? You can see the result on UI between 2 alert is different.
if so, why on the 2nd image, only number 1 rendered, not 1 2 or 1 2 3?

I am using chrome to test and expecting that nothing will be rendered on UI before 2 alert messages turn off follow the theory of critical rendering path, because javascript will block parsing and rendering process

Comment: "*why browser can renders anything on UI before all the script code finish*" and "*because javascript will block parsing and rendering process*" - it works because the `alert` script hasn't *started* yet so doesn't block the rendering up to that point.

Comment: @freedomn-m but if script does not started still block parsing process of html, right? in the second picture you can see they render 1 on UI, not all 123?

Comment: *in the second picture you can see* - no, images are blocked for me :(

Comment: Ok, so your question is actually why is `1` not rendered before alert1 but is rendered between alert1 and alert2.   This is likely just how the browser handles caching/queuing of rendering.    It doesn't render the stream line-by-line as that would be too inefficient, so it caches the rendering up to a certain amount (depending on browser/OS/memory/content etc).   The call to `alert()` stops the rendering and caching, but clicking it gives the browser a chance for the cached-so-far rendering to complete before continuing with the streaming/caching.

Comment: ie `alert()` forces a `repaint` when you click `ok`

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you for the explaination. I still have the confuse about the result. I can describe it here: when the first alert toggle on the screen, we can see the background color change to green (but I thought we need to finish layout and painting process of html before something on UI can change), and when the second alert displays, the UI also change to "1", only "1", not "1 2 3", it is strange because you can see on the html code, the script tag of test2.js is below both div 1 and div 2.

Comment: *but I thought we need to finish layout and painting process of html before something on UI can change* - this is incorrect.  You may be confusing this with DOMContentLoaded or jquery's doc.ready.   These *ensure* the HTML is available before making changes so that the code affects the elements rather than nothing.

Comment: This one will confuse you even more ;)  : https://jsfiddle.net/8dL36kbp/   In the end, don't worry about *why* it does it as that's down to the browser - different browsers may work differently (unless they use the same underlying tech of course), just make sure you know *what* it does.  (and just never use `alert()`)

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you for the answer, I think it's a bit complex for me to think to at now :D

Comment: Just don't use alert(), not even for debugging.
These are old artifacts of the web APIs and should never be used anymore. Different browsers will handle the event and render loop/chain differently when using those